# No password for Azure sandbox supplied in Python tutorial

Tags: python, azure

I am using the [Intro to Python docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/intro-to-python/)
In Unit 3, when I click Activate sandbox, I get a message

> Microsoft Learn needs your permission to create Azure resources

When I click

> Review Permissions

I get an Azure login screen with a new user name. I have not been told the password, so I can't sign in.

Comment: You have to create your own Microsoft account (https://account.microsoft.com/account?lang=en-us) and grant Azure Learn permission via Review Permissions.

Comment: Thanks, I was thrown by it creating a new login name. Care to write up the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a Microsoft Account first (https://account.microsoft.com/account?lang=en-us), then grant Microsoft Learn access via Review Permissions to begin allocating Azure resources.